# Float bug in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-float

I have a strange bug when looking at my homepage in Chrome. The bug doesn't seem to appear when I try to edit it with CSSEdit:

[image]

I attached the pictures to show you what I mean. Those "points" next to the icons are linked as well.

[image]

What could be causing this error?

Thanks for the help!

EDIT sure here's the code (the page isn't online):

```
 <div class="rss">
      <p>
         <a href="http://linkto">
             <img src="/images/facebook.png" alt="Find me on facebook" />
          </a>
          <a href="http://linkto">
            <img src="/images/twitter.png" alt="Follow me on twitter" />
          </a>
         <a href="http://linkto">
            <img src="/images/rss.png" alt="Subscribe to RSS Feed" />
          </a>
      </p>
</div>
```

which is wrapped in a div class called footer. And the CSS

```
.site .footer {
font-size: 80%;
color: #666;
border-top: 4px solid #eee;
margin-top: 2em;
overflow: hidden;
}

 .site .footer .rss {
  margin-top: 0em;
  margin-right: -.2em;
  float: right;
  }

.site .footer .rss img {
  border: 0;
}
```

Sorry for the strange formatting.

Comment: Giving the link to the actual page would be most beneficial over these images, if that's possible. This way we could at least examine the CSS and mark-up. Otherwise, are you willing to post the relevant code?

Comment: Or even the css you are using with the markup...

Comment: I might be dense, but i have no idea what bug your are talking about? What part of your layout doesn't appear like you expect it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those "points" are the `text-decoration:underline` portion of your CSS being applied to `<a>` tags. The reason you only see part of it is because the image you are using is covering the majority of it.

Try putting this in your CSS:

```
.rss a { text-decoration:none }
.rss a img { border:none; outline:none }
```

Comment: Simple fix, right? I had this problem on a couple of my pages!